# Make inner image respond to outer div size

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm working on a Toolset view in WordPress (I'm using SCSS). I've got at images that I want to fit inside a 300px x 300px div. I've tried this:

```
.container {
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;

& img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

}

I know I should use `background-image` but I can't add the custom filed to a div in the toolset view

Edit:

The toolset view code:

```
<a href="[wpv-post-url]">
<div class="project_container">
    <div class="project_text">[wpv-post-title]</div>
    [types field="projekt-bild"][/types]
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.project_row {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center; }

.project_container {
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;

.project_container img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
}
```

But when I do this all the projects are sized like the image width and height not the container that I all want them to be ex. 300px x 300px

Comment: and what your issuse because it works:https://jsfiddle.net/m3x6tc8p/

Comment: But how do I make all the containers the same size, without distorting/cropping the image inside

Comment: I think you might need to give us a verifiable eample what the problem is, because the code you gave us works fine. What do you mean with "containers"? There is only one container in your question.

Comment: @Krullmizter To help you we must see more of your code

Comment: I can not see any `img` inside `project_container`

Comment: that what you mean?https://jsfiddle.net/m3x6tc8p/1/

Comment: The image gets fetched from the shortcode

Comment: @לבני מלכה The thing is that the [types field="projekt-bild"][/types] fetches the images from a WP post. And I can't add it to a div to make it a background-image becuase "reasons..." so instead I add a div-container around the image and the text but I want all the containers/projects to be the same hight and so that the image fits properly

Comment: so you want the image behavior like `background-image`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your image to behave like CSS background-image use object-fit.

**SCSS**

```
.project_container {
    //  set relative position to make the
    //  image position to the post itself
    position: relative;

    //  random post size 
    //  not important for this to work
    width: 340px;
    height: 500px;



    img { 
        //  make image stretch to container 
        //  and show below content 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;

        //  object fit for modern browsers
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: center;

        //  fallback 
        //  using js the image source is replaced with a transparant gif
        //  and the original is added as background image
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

**JS fix** for older browsers that does not support object-fit

```
//  is object fit supported
if (document.body.style.objectFit === undefined) {

    //  loop through all images    
    [].slice
        .call(document.querySelectorAll('img'))
        .map(img => {

        //  image has background-size cover or contain        
        if(['cover', 'contain']
           .indexOf(getComputedStyle(img).backgroundSize) !== -1) {

            //  use src as background image            
            img.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img.src})`;

            //  replace src with transparent gif
            img.src = 'data:;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7';
        }
    });
}



/*

Transpiled version
if (document.body.style.objectFit === undefined) {
    [].slice
        .call(document.querySelectorAll('img'))
        .map(function (img) {
        if (['cover', 'contain']
            .indexOf(getComputedStyle(img).backgroundSize) !== -1) {
            img.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img.src + ")";
            img.src = 'data:;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7';
        }
    });
}

Transpiled and minified
void 0===document.body.style.objectFit&&[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img")).map(function(A){-1!==["cover","contain"].indexOf(getComputedStyle(A).backgroundSize)&&(A.style.backgroundImage="url("+A.src+")",A.src="data:;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7")});


*/
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/Pxwzpw

Comment: I got it wokring with object-fit, thanks! Can you vertical align the image wich is inside the container?

Comment: There is object-position but that dosen't work with object-fit

Comment: object-position does work with object-fit – like background-position :-)
article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-position – support: https://caniuse.com/#search=object-position

Comment: I've updated the demo https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/Pxwzpw to show object position and include object-fit contain

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the info, really helped and great codepen!

Answer (score 1):

As in comment you want the `image` behavior like `backgroud-img`

[see working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/m3x6tc8p/2/)

```
.project_container {
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;
position: relative;

& .project_text{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}
& img {
  width:100%;
}
}
```

Comment: happy to help :)